# Mac Yosemite virtualization

Tags: mac, virtual-machine, osx-yosemite

Is it possible to run Mac Yosemite on vmware?

For information:  Apple allows full virtualization of its operating system, provided that it is installed on Apple hardware which is also running OS X 10.7 
http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2005334

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, but I'd expect driver issues, as Yosemite will be running on VMWare or Parallels virtualized hardware drivers.

-MB

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I actually have it up and running. It's dog slow though!

Getting it installed is straight-forward:
Click New > "Install from disc or image"
Point it to 10.10 image

Comment: Thanks for sharing your test results. Please update when you hear from vmware

Comment: @iceman umm, I guess my response was cut off. See edits. the answer is YES